# What are the differences between particulars, facts, and information?

Tags: legal-terms, bangladesh

In [this tax rule](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EzYIlqOtjz3sz3aaQptYIEIGcmVUQXnF/view?usp=drivesdk), in some places **information** sharing is legalised/allowed where on the other places **particulars** sharing is legalised/allowed and elsewhere **facts** sharing is allowed though in some places all have been legalised/allowed.

What is the difference among these three terms?

Comment: Good question. Does the larger section of tax rules that contains this regulation have any definitions section? Often the beginning of a regulation will contain a set of definitions. Sometimes definitions are also contains in a statute authorizing a tax regulation to be promulgated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with this law, but if it works like other tax confidentiality laws I'm familiar with, it would be interpreted so broadly that there would effectively be no difference between "facts," "particulars" or "information."

People receiving tax returns under this law would be prohibited from disclosing any of them. Anything that is in the return would be considered secret.

Comment: in terms of protection of information all three mean same but what about disclosing of that information is allowed speecifically(e.g. particulars/facts/information..) as the question I asked?In case of disclosing information it is very sensitive to understand laws substantially because it can lead to suit in the supreme court!

Comment: Disclosing none of those is specifically allowed. Disclosing any of them is explicitly prohibited, unless it's for the purpose of administering taxes.

Comment: Ah! In attached document, there are some clauses, i.e. section 163(3), some of which is red marked, are cases when sharing/disclosing is allowed!!

Comment: Yes, but those provisions all allow disclosure *for the purpose of administering taxes.* Other uses would be prohibited.

Comment: Not all in fact! there are some exceptions which are not related to administering tax e.g. 163(3)(p). So, say,for this clause, what is the meaning of **information**?

Comment: I don't know. The statute may define it, but it's such a basic term that I'd imagine you should just consult a dictionary.

Comment: Unfortunately the statute does not define it, that's why I asked here is there any law where those terms are defined! Dictionary,in fact, does not contextually defines those terms where as that section is unquestionably executed.

Comment: @SIslam: As a general rule, if a specific legal definition is not provided by statute, the "common meaning" (e.g. such as found in a dictionary) is used. The major exception to this is when something is used in the "common meaning", becomes enshrined as a legal concept, and then the "common meaning" changes. In this case, though, the three terms are mostly interchangeable. Is what you linked an authoritative version, or a translation (e.g. English translation of Bengali)?